# Schedule Email sending from Outlook online with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

I am using Office 365, Outlook online, and send email with this script:

```
$Smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer,$SmtpPort)
$Smtp.EnableSsl = $true
$Smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username,$Password)
$Smtp.Send($Message)
```

"`$Smtp.Send($Message)`", sends email immediately, but I need to schedule sending email, how can I do it ?

Comment: You can use a scheduled task for this purpose. You might also wanna have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Task Scheduler is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a schedule task to perform this. Look the [New-ScheduleTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask) command. Note that you might need to execute your command/script with elevated privileges.

Comment: can`t find any command to schedule email,

Comment: You create a task to send an e-mail (using your own script), then create a task to invoke this method in the desired date and time.